# iPhone- Set Font list in PickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uipickerview

I have to show font list in Pickerview.  when i set fonts array in picker view delegate method then one of the font named “**Bodoni Ornaments**”  text  got distorted in picker view label, rest all fonts get showing properly.

Please see image:

[image]

I am getting font list by this code:

```
#pragma mark- Font Array return methods 

-(NSArray*)fontFamilyArrayReturnMethod
{
    NSLog (@"Font families: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
    return [UIFont familyNames];
}
```

Picker View Delegate method code:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width-7, 44)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[arrayContainFontFamily objectAtIndex:row] size:18];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayContainFontFamily objectAtIndex:row]];
    return label;    
}
```

Why this font is not coming as text in picker view label. I need font name text instead of designed character. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is arrayContainFontFamily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having taken a quick Google search for "Bodoni Ornaments", that's actually what the font looks like, so the behaviour is actually correct.

--EDIT--
Right now, you have the following line:

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[arrayContainFontFamily objectAtIndex:row] size:18];
```

This makes it so the font name is written using the font itself. You'll have to remove this line if you want "Bodoni Ornaments" to appear as text. However, you won't be able to preview each font anymore.

Comment: My question is it should say text font name instead of designed charaters in pickerview. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: @Nico, it does, but that font is symbols. If you need it to be readable then you need to use a different font...

Comment: Thanks Kamaros but i can't compro with Preview.

Comment: @Nico You can try using a NSAttributedString to display the font names along with a sample (ie, display the font name in a generic font like Helvetica and then show "ABC" or similar in the font itself), or just check for Bodoni Ornaments specifically and use a different font just for it (hacky and without a preview for that one font).

Comment: @Kamaros: Thanks for NSAttributedString option seems good, second one i have already thought but i can't cheat to user. :)